# what causes the Ruby binaries to have different version numbers in the path

Tags: ruby

look at this error message

/Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize': A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (JSON::ParserError)
    from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/json/common.rb:155:in`new'

Under what circumstances does ruby use two version numbers?

in this case I see ruby-2.2.2 and 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

`2.2.0` is the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) version (usually only interesting to people writing [extension libraries](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/extension.rdoc)) whereas `2.2.2` is the version of the Ruby implementation and in case of [MRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI) (used by you) also the language version. See [this official post](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/12/21/ruby-version-policy-changes-with-2-1-0/) for more details about its current versioning scheme.